# How to Sextante model builder within QGIS to convert KML to shapefile?

Tags: qgis, kml, qgis-modeler, sextante

Are there any tutorials on how to use Sextante within QGIS? How I could use Sextante model builder in QGIS to convert KML to shapefile?

This is a routine task and Sextante would really help.

I am straggling to find standard gdal/ogr converters within the Sextante algorithms, such as shp to kml to shp to tab.

Comment: I've looked for tutorials/docs - without success. Nor can I get model builder working (QGIS 1.8 / MacOSX 10.7), except for R scripts ([after tweaking the python code](http://press.underdiverwaterman.com/qgis-with-r-working-with-the-sextante-plugin/)).

Comment: What is the purpose? Is it satisfactory to simply open the kml in QGIS then save it as shp?

Comment: Hello Willy - the kml to shp is just part of larger list of instructions that I would like my model to do, such as (1) convert data format, (2) re-project, (3) change polygons to polylines, etc. This is a repetitive task that needs to be automated and a Sextante model would do the job. Thanks anyway for looking.

Comment: Hi Simbamangu - unfortunately I am a Windows user so difficult to help, however I share similar behaviour, some of the tools would or would not work. What I have been able to find out about QGIS Sextante plugin is that it is a relatively new project at the moment hence common bugs may exist. I am looking forward to any updates as the concept is great and working with models (multiple tools and repetitive analysis) would make it so much easier!

Comment: Try the QGIS nightly build - it has sextante 1.08 built in, vs. 1.07 in the plugin repository, and is working well for me. However, there doesn't seem to be any way to specify the output file type - I can only get it to output .shp. You might be better off using the modeler to create shapefiles and then run ogr2ogr with a batch script on the directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would tell a rather straightforward method.

If there are a couple of kml files, then they can be converted to shapefile in a manual way.

1. Just drag-drop kml in QGIS layer panel to open it;
2. Right-click layer name and "SAVE AS" shapefile;
3. Specify coordinate system;  and
4. Save/Export